# When I use lightning component in visualforce page I get Error on my visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am stuck, when I use my lightning component in visualforce page it work fine until i am not using prefix name in visualforce page. When i use prefix name then it will show error"**Something has gone wrong. Action failed: PZ33$SelectOptionsForAddress$controller$onGroup [TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {PZ3$SelectOptionsForAddress$controller$onGroup}. Please try again.**"

Visulaforce page:-

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" standardStylesheets="false" >
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.az3__LatestJquery, '/LatestJQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js')}"/>      
 <apex:includeLightning />
<div id="Con" />
 <script>
    var ContactId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
    console.log('::::'+ContactId);
        $Lightning.use("PZ3:AConfigurationApp", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent(
                    "PZ3:SelectOptionsForAddress",
                    { "ContactId" : ContactId },
                    "Con",
                    function(cmp) {
                        console.log("Component created!");
                        console.log(cmp);
                    });                        
                });
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Lightning component :-

```
<aura:component access="GLOBAL">
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/PZ__Bootstrap ,/resource/PZ3__ExternalCssForComponent" scripts='/resource/PZ3__NewRequiredJs' />
    <aura:attribute name="ContactId" type="String" default="" access="GLOBAL"/>
    <aura:attribute name="SelectAddress" type="Boolean" default="true" access="GLOBAL"/>

    <div class="body_container" >
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-xs-12 panel panel-primary panel-primary2 selectoption-page">
            <div class="panel-heading">Which address you want to validate</div>
            <div class=" panel-body panel_body_details">
                <div class="form-horizontal information-box col-xs-12" >     
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-7 control-label">Only validate mailing address </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ui:inputRadio aura:id="OnlyM" class="line"
                                      change="{!c.onGroup}" value="{v.value}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-7 control-label">Only validate other address </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ui:inputRadio aura:id="OnlyO" class="line"
                                      change="{!c.onGroup}" value="{v.value}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-7 control-label">Validate both mailing address and other address. </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ui:inputRadio aura:id="BothMO" class="line"
                                      change="{!c.onGroup}" value="{v.value}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Js:-

```
({
onGroup : function(component, event, helper) {

    var IsMailingAddress =component.find("OnlyM").get("v.value");
    var IsOtherAddress =component.find("OnlyO").get("v.value");
    var IsBothAddress =component.find("BothMO").get("v.value");
    if(IsMailingAddress){
        var rID = component.get("v.ContactId");           
            window.parent.location.href ='/apex/UpdateContactVF?id='+rID

    }
    else if(IsOtherAddress){
        var rID = component.get("v.ContactId");
        window.parent.location.href ='/apex/ContactForOtherAddressVF?id='+rID

    }else{
        var rID = component.get("v.ContactId");
        window.parent.location.href ='/apex/UpdateContactVF?id='+rID+'&SelectAddress=true'
    }
},})
```

Please help me to out of this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightning uses the [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html), which provides a secure DOM. You are not allowed to just use window.parent. Instead, you need to use [`force:navigateToURL`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm) instead, or you should be able to use window.location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when i load this visualforce page i get two error msg one is "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function throws at /resource/az3__NewRequiredJs:3:1" .

Comment: it work for this error "Something has gone wrong. Action failed: PZ33$SelectOptionsForAddress$controller$onGroup [TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {PZ3$SelectOptionsForAddress$controller$onGroup}. Please try again."